# What should be the description for this method?

Tags: java

OK this method reads a dirctor, verify the file paths are ok and then pass each file to a method and updates a Map object.
But how can i explain this for java doc. I want to create a java doc and how should i explain this method for the documentation purpose. Please tell me, if you can help me with this example, i can work for my whole project. thank you:

```
private void chckDir() {
File[] files = Dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = new File(files[i].getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    Map = getMap(file);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your method doesn't do what you said In your first sentence (doesn't verify file paths, and throws the result of getMap() away), but there's nothing wrong with putting that kind of sentence im the Javadoc.

Comment: sorry actually i stripped off some information because it was too lengthy... that is why it shows this eror.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code:

- The `break` statement will give a compilation error, I think.  It should be a `return`.
- It is bad style to name a field with a capital letter as the first character.  If `Dir` and `Map` are field names, they should be `dir` and `map` respectively.
- The statement `Map = getMap(file);` is going to repeatedly *replace* the `Map` field, and when you exit the loop, the field will refer to the object returned by the last `getmap` call.  This is probably wrong.
- Finally, change the `file` declaration as follows.  (There is no need to create a new File object ... because `getAbsoluteFile()` reurns a `File`)

  ```
  File file = files[i].getAbsoluteFile();
  ```